# Apply styles for IE 9 - 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-9, fallback

I'm coding an Angular 2 app and I need to cover with css IE 9-10. For the rest I have flexbox layout. But I need specifically cover IE 9-10 with non-flexbox styles.
I've seen a way of doing this using conditional tags in index.html, but it only applies for the specific IE 9 and nor IE 10.
Also @supports (display: flex) is not supported in those IE.
What options do I have? I want to keep flexbox scss too for IE11 >. And at the same time have a fallback for the IE 9-10.
Any suggestion and recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In this you case, can find the browser and if it is IE then apply a specific class and override the existing (flexbox into table) CSS using the class which you applied by script.  This may helps you, I have done in my one of the project which is working well.

Comment: @SatheeshKumar what approach did you use to detect the browser and apply? I mean what was the strategy? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Ivan, Using the script(jquery) below you can able to detect the browser and you can apply the class.

```
//Jquery


 if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 6 ){ 


 alert('IE 6 or below version'); 

  } 



if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 6){ 

 alert('IE above 6'); 

 } 



});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I really appreciate your help. Fortunately I don't have to support older IE for my current project.

Comment: If my answer is right in your point, please mark it as correct :), Thanks